# Can I use p-test or F-test to test for significance in this example?

Tags: statistics, regression

[image]

I'm confused at why there would be limitations to using one test or the other

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague. Generally, in simple linear regression 
$$
t ^ 2 = F,
$$
hence it does not matter which one to use to test significance. However, as this problem describes a simple linear model that was fitted for a time series, the $\epsilon$ may bear an auto-correlation of some order, hence the $t$ and $F$ statistic are not really distributed $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{F}$.